# Set selected drop down option in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a drop down with a list of results.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="item.value for item in names track by item.id">
</select>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {"id":1,"value":"NHQ"},
        {"id":2,"value":"Chapter"},
        {"id":3,"value":"Other"}
    ];
```

Now I want to pro grammatically set the selected item value in drop down .

`Still now it is initialized with blank.`

I did something like :

```
$scope.selectedName = "Other";
```

But it apparently did not work. What am I missing ?

`P.S. $scope.selectedName can be set to anything . It is just for trial , a simplified version of the problem.`

Answer (score 3):

Use `$scope.selectedName = $scope.names[2];` since `names` is an array of object and you need to provide you `select with an object` to set as default.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {"id":1,"value":"NHQ"},
        {"id":2,"value":"Chapter"},
        {"id":3,"value":"Other"}
    ];
   $scope.selectedName = $scope.names[2];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="item.value for item in names track by item.id">
</select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this

`<select ng-model="selectedName">
      <option ng-selected="selectedName === name.value" ng-repeat="name in names" value="{{name.id}}">{{name.value}}</option>
</select>`

Comment: this creates new scope for each repeated instance better to have the `ng-options`  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions